# Freeform MSM sites - no submissions received

Tags: solspace-freeform, multi-site-manager

I have a site that features MSM with Freeform pro. For the main site, all submissions are fine however for the other sites running from the main one form submissions are not received into expression engine . They do work though and email notifications are being sent, they are just not stored as submissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would need to see some code, but are you sure you have the correct form ID set for each one? Are these composer forms or template forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Freeform preferences in the EE control panel, you need to have the "Show data from all sites" preference enabled if you wish to use forms, fields and notifications across all MSM sites. :)

Comment: Thanks Max, that was the issue. Hadn't seen that preference, instantly showed all the submission as soon as I ticked the box.